# Material-Design the selected option is not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, html, material-design

I am using materlize. The problem is i have to make an option selected using jquery. All working fine when i am trying to get the value of selected option. But the only problem is the selected ption is not getting highligted. It always shown the default option text "Choose An Option"

My Html code is

```
<select id="redirect_select" name="redirect_select" onchange="showRedirect();">
    <option value="">Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="0">Use Redirect URL</option>
    <option value="1">Use Success Message</option>
</select>
```

And my script code is

```
$("#redirect_select").val("0").trigger("onchange");
```

Comment: Its working. Otherwisw direct try $("#redirect_select").val("0");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to:

1. Get the value first
2. Then change the select option after using `val("0")` without trigger

```js
function showRedirect(){
val = $("#redirect_select").val();
  alert("value is: "+val)
$("#redirect_select").val("0");

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="redirect_select" name="redirect_select" onchange="showRedirect();">
    <option value="">Choose An Option</option>
    <option value="0">Use Redirect URL</option>
    <option value="1">Use Success Message</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually i am using material-design, so the select dropdown is hidden and in place of that the input filed and ul element comes automatically